# leaflet geocoder and draggable marker show results in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, leaflet, openstreetmap

Hi I am using the following https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder to get the location on map. But When I get the result I want to have the option to move the marker so I can adjust the coordinates. I found a code that is moving the marker and shows the coordinates in a 2 fields but I have problem to join the two codes together. Also how I get the results coordinates to show in the two flields. I dont have much experience with leaflet maps so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you
Dany

my code:

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/leaflet-control-geocoder.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="map" id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
      <input id="latitude" type="text" name="latitude" />
      <input id="longitude" type="text" name="longitude" />
   </body>
   <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/leaflet-control-geocoder.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);

      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
         attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      }).addTo(map);

      L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);

      var marker = L.marker([51.441767, 5.470247],{
         draggable: true
      }).addTo(map);

      marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
         document.getElementById('latitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lat;
         document.getElementById('longitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lng;
      });
   </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply refer to Leaflet Control Geocoder [API](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder#api).

You can [customize](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder#customizing) what the plugin does with the [result](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder#geocodingresult) it receives from the search request. By default it creates a (fixed) marker, binds a popup and opens it.

In your case, you could do:

```js
var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map),
    latInput = document.getElementById('latitude'),
    lngInput = document.getElementById('longitude'),
    previousMarker;

// Customize what to do from the result.
geocoder.markGeocode = function (result) {
    var latlng = result.center;

    // Remove previous marker if any.
    if (previousMarker) {
        map.removeLayer(previousMarker);
    }

    previousMarker = L.marker(latlng, {
        draggable: true // Create a draggable marker.
    }).addTo(map).
    on('dragend', onDragEnd). // Attach position display.
    bindPopup(result.html). // Emulate Geocoder default behaviour.
    openPopup(); // bind a popup and open it right away.

    displayLatLng(latlng); // Display position right away.
};

function onDragEnd(event) {
    var latlng = event.target.getLatLng();

    displayLatLng(latlng);
}

function displayLatLng(latlng) {
    latInput.value = latlng.lat;
    lngInput.value = latlng.lng;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/11/

Comment: Great thank you that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for help

Comment: one more question how do I get to remove the old marker as I have now the original one and when I do a new search I get a next one too, thank you

Comment: Simply keep a reference of your created marker, and remove it from map at the next search result? I will edit the above code. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/15/